# Use of Parseval’s theorem for deduction

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, parsevals-identity

How would you use Parseval’s theorem to show that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k^2+1)^2}=\frac\pi4$$

Comment: Do you mean integral or sum?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Find a function $f : [-\pi, \pi] \to \mathbb R$ such that $a_k=\frac{1}{k^2+1}$ and apply Parseval Identiy.

Comment: would something like $e^-|x|$ work